# preg_replace update with preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I cannot understand how **update** from deprecation this function:

```
function kses_bad_protocol_once($string, $allowed_protocols) {
    return preg_replace('/^((&[^;]*;|[\sA-Za-z0-9])*)'.
                          '(:|&#58;|&#[Xx]3[Aa];)\s*/e',
                          'kses_bad_protocol_once2("\\1", $allowed_protocols)',
                          $string);
}
```

How I can pass to the function:

`kses_bad_protocol_once2`

the two parameter needed, converting this function with a `pref_replace_callback` one?

Comment: what is `kses_bad_protocol_once2` ?

Comment: Is another function... this function are writted by me and require 2 parameters. When the server was with PHP 5.2.6 this function work, but now the customer update the PHP server side with 5.5.14 version...